# SQL Return only specific Rows upon Condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have the following query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
                  WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = A.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR + '-A'
                  WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG4.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR + '-AG4'
                  WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG3.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR + '-AG3'
                  WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG2.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR + '-AG2'
                  WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG1.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR + '-AG1'
                END AS REFSTR
FROM   APPLICATIONGROUP AG1
       JOIN APPLICATIONGROUP AG2
         ON AG2.BELONGSTO = AG1.REFSTR
       JOIN APPLICATIONGROUP AG3
         ON AG3.BELONGSTO = AG2.REFSTR
       JOIN APPLICATIONGROUP AG4
         ON AG4.BELONGSTO = AG3.REFSTR
       JOIN RELATIONS R
         ON R.TOREF = AG4.REFSTR
            AND R.PROPERTY = 'ApplicationGroups'
       JOIN APPLICATION A
         ON A.REFSTR = R.FROMREF
       JOIN ROLE
         ON ROLE.OBJECT = A.REFSTR
             OR ROLE.OBJECT = AG1.REFSTR
             OR ROLE.OBJECT = AG2.REFSTR
             OR ROLE.OBJECT = AG3.REFSTR
             OR ROLE.OBJECT = AG4.REFSTR
       JOIN ROLETYPE RT
         ON RT.REFSTR = ROLE.ROLETYPE
            AND RT.NAME = 'BC Coordinator'
       JOIN PERSON P
         ON P.REFSTR = ROLE.RESPONSIBLE
WHERE  A.REFSTR = '326-1480-0'
```

It gives me the following Records Returned;

```
REFSTR
273-1123-0-A
273-18075-0-AG4
273-26853-0-AG3
273-27196-0-AG2
273-3235-0-AG1
```

What i am looking for is a way to only show the first record if it exists so;
If the record '%A' is selected then just show '%A' if record '%A' is not shown then show '%AG4' ect.

So the need is to output the record if found in the Table application, if not found then the ApplicationGroup AG4 if this is not found then AG3 and so on.

---

An update as maybe i was not clear enough in my original Question.

1. I have a hierarchy of applicationGroups AG1 = Parent, AG2 Child of AG1, AG3 Child of AG2, AG4 Child of AG3. This is handled by the Parent REFSTR = BELONGSTO of the child.
2. I have an application which is linked to the AG4 Group, the linkage is handled in the table Relations. So application.REFSTR = Relation.FROMREF and AG4.REFSTR = Relation.TOREF.
3. On each of these Objects A, AG1, AG2, AG3, AG4 i can assign a Responsibility (BC Coordinator) which is a Reference to a Person. This is handled in the table ROLE, so the OBJECT references either the Application A or one of the ApplicationGroups (AG1, AG2, AG3, AG4), This then references the Person over ROLE.RESPONSIBLE = PERSON.REFSTR. The final join here is the ROLETYPE.REFSTR = ROLE.ROLETYPE which controls the (BC Coordinator) as a specific RoleType.This assignment of responsibility can be 1-1 or 1-n at any level.

The requirement is as follows;

1. I need to look starting at the application A if an assignment of the Responsibility (BC Coordinator) if this exists then give me all persons who have this either 1 or many.
2. If nothing is found on the application then Look at the ApplicationGroup AG4 where the application A is assigned to. Again either 1 or many.
3. If nothing is found on the ApplicationGroup AG4 then look at its parent ApplicationGroup AG3.
4. If nothing is found on the ApplicationGroup AG3 then look at its Parent ApplicationGroup AG2.
5. If nothing is found on the ApplicationGroup AG2 Then look at its Parent ApplicationGroup AG1.
6. If still nothing is found then no result.

The Issue i am having is this logic to go from one level to another, as to my previous comment a TOP 1 using this query would work if it was just always getting 1 result, however this could be many results at any level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue using the following code from a collegue: Many thanks for the tips.

```
     WITH TMP AS(

SELECT DISTINCT CASE    
        WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = A.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR  
        WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG4.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR  
        WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG3.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR 
        WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG2.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR  
        WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG1.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR  
                END AS REFSTR,
                CASE    
        WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = A.REFSTR THEN '1' 
        WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG4.REFSTR THEN '2'  
        WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG3.REFSTR THEN '3' 
        WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG2.REFSTR THEN '4'  
        WHEN ROLE.OBJECT = AG1.REFSTR THEN '5'  
                END AS LEVEL
  FROM APPLICATIONGROUP AG1 
  JOIN APPLICATIONGROUP AG2 ON 
    AG2.BELONGSTO = AG1.REFSTR
  JOIN APPLICATIONGROUP AG3 ON 
    AG3.BELONGSTO = AG2.REFSTR
  JOIN APPLICATIONGROUP AG4 ON 
    AG4.BELONGSTO = AG3.REFSTR
  JOIN RELATIONS R ON 
    R.TOREF = AG4.REFSTR AND R.PROPERTY = 'ApplicationGroups'
  JOIN APPLICATION A ON 
    A.REFSTR = R.FROMREF
  JOIN ROLE ON 
    ROLE.OBJECT = A.REFSTR OR 
    ROLE.OBJECT = AG1.REFSTR OR 
    ROLE.OBJECT = AG2.REFSTR OR 
    ROLE.OBJECT = AG3.REFSTR OR 
    ROLE.OBJECT = AG4.REFSTR 

  JOIN ROLETYPE RT ON 
    RT.REFSTR = ROLE.ROLETYPE AND RT.NAME = 'BC Coordinator'
  JOIN PERSON P ON 
    P.REFSTR = ROLE.RESPONSIBLE


  WHERE A.REFSTR = '326-1480-0' )

**SELECT REFSTR FROM TMP 
GROUP BY REFSTR,LEVEL
HAVING LEVEL = (SELECT MIN(LEVEL) FROM TMP)**
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a shot in the dark here but maybe something like this?

```
SELECT TOP 1
    P.REFSTR + '-A' +
    CASE    
        WHEN r.OBJECT = AG4.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR + 'G4'
        WHEN r.OBJECT = AG3.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR + 'G3'
        WHEN r.OBJECT = AG2.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR + 'G2' 
        WHEN r.OBJECT = AG1.REFSTR THEN P.REFSTR + 'G1'
    END AS REFSTR
FROM APPLICATIONGROUP AG1 
JOIN APPLICATIONGROUP AG2 ON AG2.BELONGSTO = AG1.REFSTR
JOIN APPLICATIONGROUP AG3 ON AG3.BELONGSTO = AG2.REFSTR
JOIN APPLICATIONGROUP AG4 ON AG4.BELONGSTO = AG3.REFSTR
JOIN RELATIONS R ON R.TOREF = AG4.REFSTR AND R.PROPERTY = 'ApplicationGroups'
JOIN APPLICATION A ON A.REFSTR = R.FROMREF
JOIN ROLE R ON r.OBJECT = A.REFSTR OR r.OBJECT = AG1.REFSTR OR r.OBJECT = AG2.REFSTR OR r.OBJECT = AG3.REFSTR OR r.OBJECT = AG4.REFSTR
JOIN ROLETYPE RT ON RT.REFSTR = r.ROLETYPE AND RT.NAME = 'BC Coordinator'
JOIN PERSON P ON P.REFSTR = r.RESPONSIBLE
WHERE A.REFSTR = '326-1480-0'
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN R.OBJECT = A.REFSTR THEN 1
    WHEN R.OBJECT = AG4.REFSTR THEN 2
    WHEN R.OBJECT = AG3.REFSTR THEN 3
    WHEN R.OBJECT = AG2.REFSTR THEN 4
    WHEN R.OBJECT = AG1.REFSTR THEN 5
END
```

Comment: Thanks the TOP1 gets me the results that i am looking for however for Any of these classes there could be multiple and i would need all of them so if 2 records came for A then 2 if no A and 2 on AG4 then the 2 from AG4

Comment: That kind of contradicts what you stated in your question. Seems you need to provide a bit more explanation.

Comment: Hi please look at my main question i have made it hopefully more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

create REFSTR as table

Use if exists (do it for all cases)

If exists(select *

from REFSTR

where xxx like'%-A')

then

begin

select *

from REFSTR

where xxx like'%-a'

end

Else...(case -AG4)

Comment: Thanks, the main issue is in the software i have i can only start a query with (WITH xxx as) or (Select)

Comment: WITH xxx as (your query) select (my query)